# Converting Excel to CSV with SSIS

Tags: ssis

I found code to use in my script task below, to convert my excel files to CSV files and put them in a seperate folder.  But my files only have one sheet (so think there is extra code), but also when it converts it over the column header is removed.  I also set up SSIS variables for (destination, source, and file dlimiter) Any suggestions:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        #region Help:  Using Integration Services variables and parameters in a script
        /* To use a variable in this script, first ensure that the variable has been added to 
         * either the list contained in the ReadOnlyVariables property or the list contained in 
         * the ReadWriteVariables property of this script task, according to whether or not your
         * code needs to write to the variable.  To add the variable, save this script, close this instance of
         * Visual Studio, and update the ReadOnlyVariables and 
         * ReadWriteVariables properties in the Script Transformation Editor window.
         * To use a parameter in this script, follow the same steps. Parameters are always read-only.
         * 
         * Example of reading from a variable:
         *  DateTime startTime = (DateTime) Dts.Variables["System::StartTime"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of writing to a variable:
         *  Dts.Variables["User::myStringVariable"].Value = "new value";
         * 
         * Example of reading from a package parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Package::batchId"].Value;
         *  
         * Example of reading from a project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
         * 
         * Example of reading from a sensitive project parameter:
         *  int batchId = (int) Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].GetSensitiveValue();
         * */

        #endregion

        #region Help:  Firing Integration Services events from a script
        /* This script task can fire events for logging purposes.
         * 
         * Example of firing an error event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireError(18, "Process Values", "Bad value", "", 0);
         * 
         * Example of firing an information event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, "Process Values", "Processing has started", "", 0, ref fireAgain)
         * 
         * Example of firing a warning event:
         *  Dts.Events.FireWarning(14, "Process Values", "No values received for input", "", 0);
         * */
        #endregion

        #region Help:  Using Integration Services connection managers in a script
        /* Some types of connection managers can be used in this script task.  See the topic 
         * "Working with Connection Managers Programatically" for details.
         * 
         * Example of using an ADO.Net connection manager:
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  SqlConnection myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Sales DB"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         *
         * Example of using a File connection manager
         *  object rawConnection = Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
         *  string filePath = (string)rawConnection;
         *  //Use the connection in some code here, then release the connection
         *  Dts.Connections["Prices.zip"].ReleaseConnection(rawConnection);
         * */
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called when this script task executes in the control flow.
        /// Before returning from this method, set the value of Dts.TaskResult to indicate success or failure.
        /// To open Help, press F1.
        /// </summary>
        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string SourceFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::SourcePath"].Value.ToString();
            string DestinationFolderPath = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationPath"].Value.ToString();
            string FileDelimited = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(SourceFolderPath);
            FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

            //Declare and initilize variables
            string fileFullPath = "";

            //Get one Book(Excel file at a time)
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string filename = "";
                fileFullPath = SourceFolderPath + "\\" + file.Name;
                filename = file.Name.Replace(".xlsx", "");
                MessageBox.Show(fileFullPath);

                //Create Excel Connection
                string ConStr;
                string HDR;
                HDR = "YES";
                ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileFullPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
                OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);


                //Get Sheet Name
                cnn.Open();
                DataTable dtSheet = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                string sheetname;
                sheetname = "";
                Int16 sheetcnt = 0;
                foreach (DataRow drSheet in dtSheet.Rows)
                {
                    sheetcnt += 1;
                    if (drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("$"))
                    {
                        sheetname = drSheet["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                        //Display Sheet Name , you can comment it out
                        // MessageBox.Show(sheetname);

                        //Load the DataTable with Sheet Data
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + sheetname + "]", cnn);
                        //cnn.Open();
                        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        adp.Fill(dt);

                        //drop $from sheet name
                        sheetname = sheetname.Replace("$", "");

                        //Create CSV File and load data to it from Sheet
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DestinationFolderPath + "\\" + filename + ".csv", true);
                        int ColumnCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                        //we are checking SheetCnt=1, so put header in csv for only one time
                        if (sheetcnt == 1)
                        {
                            // Write the Header Row to File
                            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
                            {
                                sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                                if (i < ColumnCount - 1)
                                {
                                    sw.Write(FileDelimited);
                                }
                            }
                            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                        }


                        // Write All Rows to the File
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                                {
                                    sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                                }
                                if (i < ColumnCount - 1)
                                {
                                    sw.Write(FileDelimited);
                                }
                            }
                            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                        }
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Sorry first time question here!!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is making the header not come over in this scenario?

Comment: add a breakpoint and step through it. Specifically on this line 
if (sheetcnt == 1)